# Python project basing on picture to guess the answer for the flag name , I think that the while loop is the problem

Tags: python, tkinter

My code snippet:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import Label, Canvas, PhotoImage, Frame, Entry, Button

# Create the function instruction.
def instruction():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Welcome To the Flag Guessing Game',
                                'You have 3 attempts to play this game '
                                'There are 6 countries in this game '
                                'you can answer AU for Australia,  JP for Japan , '
                                'NO for Norway,'
                                ' NRA for Nigeria, '
                                'NL for Netherland, '
                                'UK for United Kingdom')


# Create the function for show the picture on frame.
def image_start():
    first_image = Label(frame1, image=Image1)
    first_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


def image_two():
    second_image = Label(frame1, image=Image2)
    second_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


def image_three():
    second_image = Label(frame1, image=Image3)
    second_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


def image_forth():
    second_image = Label(frame1, image=Image4)
    second_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


def image_fifth():
    second_image = Label(frame1, image=Image5)
    second_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


def image_sixth():
    second_image = Label(frame1, image=Image6)
    second_image.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')


turns = 3
# Create the function for button and check the entry,
while turns > 0:
    def flag_check(entry):
        # create the global variable turns
        global turns
        # if the answer is AU, it will be right and move to next image
        if entry == "AU":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
            image_two()
            if entry == "JP":
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
                image_three()
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
                turns -= 1
                if entry == 'Netherlands' or entry == 'NL':
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
                    image_forth()
                else:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
                    turns -= 1
                    if entry == 'Nigeria' or entry == 'NRA':
                        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
                        image_fifth()
                    else:
                        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
                        turns -= 1
                        if entry == 'United Kingdom' or entry == 'UK':
                            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
                            image_sixth()
                        else:
                            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
                            turns -= 1
                            if entry == 'Norway' or entry == 'NO':
                                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')
                            else:
                                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
                                turns -= 1
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')
            turns -= 1
else:
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong 3 times, Sorry Game Over')
# Create the root windows.
root = tkinter.Tk()
width = 1000
height = 800
Image1 = PhotoImage(file='Australia.png')
Image2 = PhotoImage(file='Japan.png')
Image3 = PhotoImage(file='Netherlands.png')
Image4 = PhotoImage(file='Nigeria.png')
Image5 = PhotoImage(file='UK.png')
Image6 = PhotoImage(file='Norway.png')
# Create the canvas with the height and width we want, here I use 1000 and 800 which stored in the variable above
canvas = Canvas(root, height=height, width=width)
canvas.pack()
# Create the background of the game by using PhotoImage.
background = PhotoImage(file='USA.png')
label_background = Label(root, image=background)
label_background.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
# Create the frame on the top which content the question and instruction for game.
frame1 = Frame(root, bg='#0a202b', bd=10)
frame1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.85, relheight=0.7, anchor='n')
label = Label(frame1)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
# Create the button and entry in frame2 for user can submit the answer.
frame2 = Frame(root, bg='#0a202b', bd=10)
frame2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.85, relheight=0.15, anchor='n')
entry = Entry(frame2, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.6, relheight=1)
button = Button(frame2, text="Submit", font=12, bg='grey', command=lambda: flag_check(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.65, relwidth=0.35, relheight=1)
image_start()
title = Label(root, text="Welcome To the Flag Guessing Game", font=120, bg='white')
title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.05, anchor='n')
# info = Button(root, text="Welcome To the Flag Guessing Game", font=100, command=instruction)
info = Button(root, text="Click here for instruction", font=100, bg='grey', command=instruction)
info.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.65, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.05, anchor='n')
textbox = Label(frame2, text="Your answer: ", font=100, bg='white')
textbox.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.03, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.2)
# Call the first image show on frame1.
root.mainloop()
```

I want to program a guessing game basing on the image of the flags from different countries. There are 6 countries which I picked. The user will have maximum 3 turns, if they are wrong 3 times, the game will end. The user cannot move to the next image until they guess correctly the current image right. I think the problem is the loop.

Comment: I have been working this project for a week and I still cannot figure out. Therefore, I wonder that anyone can help me direction for my code. I think that the problem is the loop because when I test one image of flag is ok but when add another one, it cannot come the way I want. I want that the user have to guess the right answer to move on the next level. Therefore, I am appreciate if anyone can help me a direction to make it work.

Comment: You have not declare tkinter objects correctly, use  `tkinter.` on all your objects.

Comment: The second problem deals with function `flag_check`, you've put it inside a `while` structure. This prevents your `tkinter` code from initializing.

Comment: I have your code partially working but you need to prepend all `tkinter` objects with `tkinter.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask an actual question*. In particular, what happens when you run the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style of writing code is not that much right, if you are doing same things every time then you can turn that same things into a function and can call function is you need it and you are doing everything statically which is not a good practice. I have change most of the code you may not exactly understand but play with it and you will eventually understand it.

Explanation :
Variable `n` is for level like things and `b` is to making sure program will not check 2 condition while checking answer. `msg` function is for success message and `msgwrng` function is for wrong answer. I have changed the variable name of `Entry` from `entry` to `entrybox`. I haven't changed other things which should be changed but I think you will understand from here and change those code also.

Here's your code. If you find anything wrong or didn't understand anything ask in comment section.

If it helped you don't forget to mark this as answer, it will help for future programmer also.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

turns = 3

def msg():
    messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'Congratulation, you got it!')

def msgwrng():
    messagebox.showinfo('Answer', 'You are wrong')

# Create the function for button and check the entry,

def flag_check(entry):
    # create the global variable turns 
    global turns,n
    if turns>0:
        b=1
        if n==1:
            if entry == "AU":
                msg()
                image_two()
                n+=1
                b=0
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
        if n==2 and b==1:
            if entry == "JP":
                msg()
                image_three()
                n+=1
                b=0
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
        if n==3 and b==1:
            if entry == 'Netherlands' or entry == 'NL':
                msg()
                image_forth()
                n+=1
                b=0
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
        if n==4 and b==1:
            if entry == 'Nigeria' or entry == 'NRA':
                msg()
                image_fifth()
                n+=1
                b=0
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
        if n==5 and b==1:
            if entry == 'United Kingdom' or entry == 'UK':
                msg()
                image_sixth()
                n+=1
                b=0
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
        if n==6 and b==1:
            if entry == 'Norway' or entry == 'NO':
                msg()
            else:
                msgwrng()
                turns -= 1
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Finished","All answer were wrong")
    entrybox.delete(0,END)


n=1
#create the root windows
root = Tk()
width = 1000
height = 800


entrybox = Entry(frame2, font=40)
entrybox.place(relwidth=0.6, relheight=1)

button = Button(frame2, text="Submit", font=12, bg = 'grey', command=lambda: flag_check(entrybox.get()))
button.place(relx=0.65, relwidth=0.35, relheight=1)
```

Comment: I understand the n is level, but I do not understand b variable, can you explain me that part please? The entrybox.delete is the one we need to do to end the entry from user and end the game? I am very appreciate for your work. Thank you

Comment: Try deleting b from everywhere and see result, Its called playing with variables.For the end of game, I had done for doing 3 wrong and you can do end of game in `if n==6` part because that's the last question.I am doing entry.delete because user have to delete manually after giving answers but I don't feel good about deleting manually because I have to write again in that same field the it should be clear if my answer is correct.Just play with it, try deleting and adding stuff in it. You will understand values of all variables.It is the basic process of learning.

Comment: @TrangDo You haven't marked this as answer, haven't this helps you to solve your problem?

Comment: I have been playing with it and delete the whole variable and I notice that when the b out, they show the answer is you are wrong right after the next image show which it is not support to do it. Thank you, it helped me a lot. I try to play with it now. I marked it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

It is greatly simplified but shows one way to implement your game.

Obviously I'm not able to access your images so I've replaced them with words
I've modified the code to include your images instead of words.

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

def instruction():
    messagebox.showinfo(
    title='Instructions',
    message = 'Welcome To the Flag Guessing Game',
    detail = """You have 3 attempts to play this game.
There are 6 countries in this game.
You can answer:
    AU for Australia
    JP for Japan
    NO for Norway
    NRA for Nigeria
    NL for Netherland
    UK for United Kingdom""")

turns, n = 3, 0
# diction to store questions and text
# replace them with images

def flag_check( event ):
    global turns, n

    Answer = entry.get( ).upper()
    entry.delete( '0', 'end' )

    if Answer == question[ n ].upper():
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Correct' )
        n += 1
        if n == len( question ):
            messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Congratulations\nYou win' )
            root.destroy()
        else:
            label[ 'image' ] = clue[ n ]
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Wrong' )
        turns -= 1
    if turns < 0:
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Failed' )
        root.destroy()


root = tkinter.Tk()

questions = dict(
    Australia = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Australia.png')
    Japan = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Japan.png')
    Netherlands = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Netherlands.png')
    Nigeria = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Nigeria.png')
    Britain = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='UK.png')
    Norway = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Norway.png')

question = list( questions.keys() )
clue = list( questions.values() )

#  replace text with image
label = tkinter.Label( root, image=clue[ n ] )
label.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

info = tkinter.Button(
    root, text="Click here for instruction",
    font = 'Consolas 20 normal', command=instruction)
info.grid( row=1, column=0,sticky='nsew')

entry = tkinter.Entry( root, font = 'Consolas 20 normal' )
entry.grid( row=2, column=0,sticky='nsew')
entry.bind( '<Return>', flag_check )
entry.focus()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am new to Python, can you explain for me this part  Answer = entry.get( ).upper()
    entry.delete( '0', 'end' )

    if Answer == question[ n ].upper():
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Correct' )
        n += 1
        if n == len( question ):
            messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Congratulations\nYou win' )
            root.destroy()
        else:
            label[ 'image' ] = clue[ n ]
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Wrong' )
        turns -= 1
    if turns < 0:
        messagebox.showinfo( message = 'Failed' )
        root.destroy()

Comment: Sorry about the delay, `entry.get( ).upper()` will retrieve user input from entry and convert it to uppercase.

Comment: I edited my code to include your images. Did that work OK?

Comment: Oh yeah I see, `Answer == question[ n ].upper()` is necessary so that user does not have to match the exact punctuation in the question. `n` is used to access each question and replaces the conditional testing. This means you can increase the number of flags simply by adding more `questions`.